# Unable to use multiple <v-app-bar > in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use multiple  for displaying logo and menus.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to show logo's only in one v-app-bar and menus in another  v-app-bar .My code is similar to like this. Please help me

```
<v-app-bar app flat>
        <v-img
          :src="require('@/assets/test.png')"
          class="mr-5"
          contain
          height="170"
          width="200"
          max-width="170"
          :to="{ name: 'home' }"
        /> 
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
         <v-img
          :src="require('@/assets/test.png')"
          class="mr-5 ml-5"
          contain
          height="170"
          width="200"
          max-width="170"
          :to="{ name: 'dashboard' }"
        />
      </v-col>
       <v-col cols="4">
         <v-img
          :src="require('@/assets/test.png')"
          class="mr-5"
          contain
          height="170"
          width="200"
          max-width="170"
          :to="{ name: 'home' }"
        /> 
    <v-container class="mx-auto py-0">
    <v-row width="100%">  
          <router-link :to="{ path: '/' }" class="link">Home</router-link>     
        <v-menu offset-y>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">     
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'contact' }" class="link"> Contact Us</router-link>           
          </template>
        </v-menu>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app-bar>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the menus app bar below the image ?

Comment: yes, I want to show the menu bar below the logo bar. I want to make two bar for logos and menus. @beingyogi

Comment: You can have multiple toolbars, only one v-app-bar can be added at a place (top or bottom). V-app-bar is using for primary navigation.

Comment: When I used v-toolbar and v-app-bar together , it doesnot work. @beingyogi

Comment: Remove v-app-bar and add 2 toolbar in 2 rows and make the toolbar fixed. I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Can I ask a question? @beingyogi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222159/discussion-between-beingyogi-and-prabina-sht).

Comment: hello ! Can I ask a question? @beingyogi

Comment: Yes you can create a question

Comment: I have a created a question. @beingyogi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587128/unable-to-copy-an-array-to-an-array-using-vue-js/64587278#64587278

Answer (score 3):

### Steps to add multiple abb bars in vuetify 2.x

1. use `extension-height` prop to extend the `v-app-bar` height
2. define height for extension-height. Example: `extension-height="64"`
3. define a scoped slot called `extension` inside the `v-app-bar`
4. inside this slot: add a `v-toolbar` with the same height as defined in `extension-height` prop

### working demo

*click on the codepen icon*

[image: 2]