# Unable to copy an array to an array using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a multiple selectbox using vuetify select component. I'm getting array of selected items and I want to merge status as true of selected items like `[ { "ward": 1, "status": true }, { "ward": 2, "status": true} ]`
I'm trying to copy selected items of array to another array but couldn't succeed. In console, I got selectedFruits as below.

[image]

[image]

```
 methods: {
    save() {
      console.log(this.selectedFruits);
      debugger;    
      this.selectedIndex.push({ ward: this.selectedFruits, status: true });
      console.log(this.list);
    },
```

Comment: When is save method called and what does `this.selectedfruits` and `this.list` contains

Comment: When I select from selectbox and submit form , save method is called. @deceze

Comment: And do you want `[ { "ward": 1, "status": true }, { "ward": 2, "status": true} ]` in `this.list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
save(){
  this.list = []
  this.selectedFruits.forEach(e => {
      this.list.push({ ward: e, status: true });
    });
    console.log(this.list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an array or object without passing it by reference, do it like this

```
const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Spread-Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for this.

Here an example:

```js
const existingArr = [{ hi: 'foobar' }];
const arr = [{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}, { a: 'hello',  b: 'world'}]
const newArr = [...existingArr, ...arr]

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: When I did    const newData = [({ ward: this.selectedFruits, status: true })], I'm getting newData as undefined. @S.Visser

Comment: Why are there `( )` in there?

Comment: When I remove ( ) , i'm still  getting undefined. @S.Visser

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with an example.